# Parse svn log -xml date output using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, xml, svn, simpledateformat, java.util.date

The date format of the xml output of the svn log command is like the following.

```
2014-04-24T08:51:58.213757Z
```

I tried to parse this to a util.Date object using SimpleDateFormat with the following String.

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ
```

Complete method

```
protected Date formatDate(String dateString) {
        //2014-04-24T08:51:58.213757Z

        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS");
        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Colombo"));
        Date date = null;
        int lengthToParse = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS".length();

        try {
            date = format.parse(dateString.substring(0, lengthToParse));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return date;
    }
```

However this gives an error as follows.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'T'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to quote the `T` because you want it to match literally. You also want `X` as the format specifier for the time zone, not `Z`:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSX
```

Or you could specify the time zone as UTC, and quote the Z as well.

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'
```

However, you may still have problems because that's going to interpret 213757 as a number of milliseconds, not microseconds.

I'm not sure there's a clean way of parsing microseconds with `SimpleDateFormat` - you're probably best off just parsing a substring:

```
String text = "2014-04-24T08:51:58.213567Z";
// You could just hard code the length, but this feels easier to read
String trimmed = text.substring(0, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS".length());
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC");
Date date = format.parse(trimmed);
```

Note that you definitely want `Etc/UTC` as the time zone, because the *input* is in UTC... that's what the 'Z' means at the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks! I have a little trouble in understanding the parsing of the string. Parsing "2014-04-24T08:51:58.213" with the above format string results in a Data object with values "Thu Apr 24 08:52:19 IST 2014". I'm setting the timezone to the local one, on which this value was saved (svn server being on the same timezone). I'm not sure why this difference is occurring.

Comment: @Chamila: A `java.util.Date` doesn't *have* a time zone... but calling `toString()` always formats it in your system local time zone. But I'm *very* suspicious of the value changing seconds like that... I've just noticed a flaw in my code though, which could be the problem - check in a second. (It's just the substring call that I've changed.)

Comment: I checked my code and I had actually included the start index :). I did an evaluation on toString() too but resulted in the same difference in seconds. I'm planning to use Joda-Time library for DateTime purposes. It can take a ISO-8601 formatted string as input and seems to have no unusual behavior. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Chamila: Please update your question with a short but complete program demonstrating that. It really should be fine. I'd expect to see a difference in hours and minutes when it converted the UTC to your local time zone, but not in the seconds...

Comment: @Chamila: If you're planning to use Joda Time (which I'd thoroughly recommend) why did you ask about SimpleDateFormat? Just go straight to Joda Time...

Comment: Came across joda-time when I was researching this difference in seconds issue. Kept it aside for now, adjusted the tests to comply. But I will soon switch. :)

Comment: @Chamila: Righto, that makes sense. It's a much better API in all respects :)

Comment: @Chamila: You've updated the code with a single method, but you haven't shown the input or output. Again, it would be useful to show a *complete* program which we can compile and run. And you've specified the wrong time zone - the input is in UTC, *not* in Asia/Colombo. That's what the 'Z' on the end means. And the code you've posted still doesn't quote the 'T'.